# Alpaca + Meteor: How to address form from within button handlers?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I appreciate the meteor package for alpaca created here [ahdinosaur/meteor-alpaca-bootstrap](https://github.com/ahdinosaur/meteor-alpaca-bootstrap). It seems to differ subtly from a more standard installation of alpaca. Some of the examples from the Alpaca docs aren't working for me with this package.  For instance, this simple example as part of a schema definition from the [Alpaca docs](http://alpacajs.org/docs/api/forms.html) results in a console error:

```
// alpaca options
"options": {
    "buttons": {
        "submit": {
            "click": function() {
                if (this.isValid(true)) {
                    var value = this.getValue();
                }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This results in

```
The compiled template: view-formButtonsContainer for view: VIEW_BOOTSTRAP_EDIT_LIST 
    failed to execute: {"message":"renderedForm is not defined"}
The compiled template: view-form for view: VIEW_BOOTSTRAP_EDIT_LIST failed to execute: 
    {"message":"Alpaca caught an error with the default error handler: The compiled template: 
    view-formButtonsContainer for view: VIEW_BOOTSTRAP_EDIT_LIST failed to execute: 
    {\"message\":\"renderedForm is not defined\"}"}
```

Or this variation also from the Alpaca doc also errors ({\"message\":\"renderedForm is not defined\"}"}):

```
if (renderedForm.isValid(true)) {
    value = renderedForm.getValue();
    alert(JSON.stringify(value, null, "  "));
}
```

I'm pretty sure if I weren't a JS neophyte, this would be trivial to fix, but for me it is a stumper.

I'd love to see some examples in the README of some variations of working code using this meteor package so I can adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

First, Meteor has a handy package management system called atmosphere and you should be able to install the alpaca-bootstrap package by typing:
 `meteor add mrt:alpaca-bootstrap`. Then you can also get some nice stats like # of installs through [the atmosphere site](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/alpaca-bootstrap).

Second, it's unclear where you're putting your code. Is your schema definition in your js file? You should be doing it in the Template.myTemplate.created callback. Take a look at: [Meteor and Alpaca forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096522/meteor-and-alpaca-forms) and http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_created

Comment: Thanks @katogeaver. No I got that far. Pretty familiar with Meteor at this point. I've installed and used a half dozen meteor packages successfully. The code is in a js file associated with the appropriate template as part of the alpaca options definition just south of the schema. I know it is being included properly. In fact without this button code the alpaca form renders properly. The question remaining is how given a button press do I refer to the form contents?